# How can I artificially nest schemas in Marshmallow?

Tags: python, serialization, marshmallow

In Marshmallow, is there a way to pass the current object to a `Nested` field in order to produce artificially nested serializations? For example, consider this object that I'm serializing:

```
example = Example(
    name="Foo",
    address="301 Elm Street",
    city="Kalamazoo",
    state="MI",
)
```

I want to produce JSON for this that looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "Foo",
    "address": {
            "street": "301 Elm Street",
            "city": "Kalamazoo",
            "state": "MI"
    }
}
```

Essentially, this would be a nested `AddressSchema` inside the `ExampleSchema`, something like this:

```
class AddressSchema:
    street = fields.String(attribute="address")
    city = fields.String()
    state = fields.String()

class ExampleSchema:
    name = fields.String()
    address = fields.Nested(AddressSchema)
```

...but that doesn't quite do what I'd like. I can use a custom function, but I'd like to use a built-in method if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to figure out a solution that allows me to preserve introspection and use only built-in fields; it's a little odd, though. I modified `ExampleSchema` to include a `@pre_dump` hook that adds a self-referential attribute, and pointed the field at that:

```
class ExampleSchema:
    name = fields.String()
    address = fields.Nested(
        AddressSchema, attribute="_marshmallow_self_reference"
    )

    @pre_dump
    def add_self_reference(self, data):
        setattr(data, "_marshmallow_self_reference", data)
```

Comment: If you get an `got an unexpected keyword argument 'many'` error, you need to append `**kwargs` to the end of the pre_dump function declaration, see [here](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/issues/1630#issuecomment-658711243)

Answer (score 1):

You can define the address field as follows

```
address = fields.Function(lambda x: {'street': x.street, 'city': x.city, 'state': x.state})
```

Credit goes to this post: [Nesting in Python and Marshmallow with a field that does not exist in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68836247/nesting-in-python-and-marshmallow-with-a-field-that-does-not-exist-in-the-databa)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the accepted answer to work. I wanted to nest some members as as a "preferences" schema inside the account.

```
class Color:
    id = Column(UUID)
    name = Column(Unicode(100))

class Account:
    id = Column(UUID())
    name = Column(Integer())
    age = Column(Integer())

    # These are the account's "preferences", which are stored
    # directly in the account model.
    color_ids = Column(ARRAY(UUID))
    colors = relationship("Color", primaryjoin... etc)
    opt_in = Column(Boolean())
```

I used marshmallow's `pre_dump` decorator to call a function that sets a preferences object onto the model:

```
class ColorSchema(SQLAlchemySchema):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Color
        fields = [ "id", "name" ]

# Subset of Account that I want returned as a nested entry
class PreferencesSchema(SQLAlchemySchema):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Account
        fields = [ "colors", "opt_in" ]

    colors = marshmallow.fields.List(marshmallow.fields.Nested(ColorSchema))

class AccountSchema(SQLAlchemySchema):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Account
        fields = [
            "id",
            "name",
            "age",
            "preferences" # Note: does not exist on model
        ]
    preferences = fields.Nested(PreferencesSchema)

    @pre_dump
    def set_preferences(self, data, **kwargs):
        preferences = {
            "colors": data.colors,
            "opt_in": data.opt_in,
        }
        setattr(data, "preferences", preferences)
        return data
```

Now the response would be:

```
{
    "id": "uuid...",
    "name": "Joe",
    "age": 25,
    "preferences": {
        "colors": [
            { "id": "uuid...", "name": "blue" },
            { "id": "uuid...", "name": "red" },
        ],
        "opt_in": false
    }
 }
```